# how to center span in div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a div and inside I have an image and a span with text.  How do I center the span in whats left of the div?  Essentially I'm trying to move the text to the right but do so in a way that will work for a responsive design

```html
  <div class="site-title">
<img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-newswagimage-1.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%">
<span style="color:#518234;text-align:ce
  nter;">Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate
</span>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `<span>` `display: inline-block`, and additionally give it a `width` that is slightly under the remaining space. It already has `text-align: center` on it, though note that this isn't correctly applying in your snippet due to the line break. Fixing this up and both changing the `display` and adding the `width` will align the text in the center of the remaining space:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="site-title">
  <img style="vertical-align:middle" src="https://sustainablewestonma.000webhostapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/cropped-newswagimage-1.jpg" class="header-image" width="25%">
  <span style="color:#518234;text-align:center;">Educate ● Initiate ● Collaborate
</span>
</div>
```